# Как работать с SQLite в Android 7.1.2?

Tags: unity3d, sqlite, unity3d-android

При работе с Unity cтолкнулся с такой проблемой.
Приложение работает с базой данных SQLite при помощи плагина, но при тестировании на Android 7.1.2 выпал в ошибку, на предыдущих версиях все работает стабильно.
В поисках решения проблемы наткнулся на статью http://ericsink.com/entries/sqlite_android_n.html
но так и не понял что делать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обновил SQLite3 на SQLite4 с гита https://github.com/codecoding/SQLite4Unity3d